# Value variable as 0 not as false in shorthand-if expression

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shorthand, shorthand-if

I'm calling a function in either those two ways

`foo([x,y])` or `foo({x:x,y:y})`  with `x,y ∈ [0,∞)`

the foo function looks like this

```
var x = pos.x || pos[0],
    y = pos.y || pos[1];
```

If I call the function the second way with `x=0` then `pos.x` will be valuated as false, which leaves `x=pos[0]` that is `undefined`.

I wondered whether there is way for `0` not valuated as `false` like in the longhand method with `if(pos.x===0){/*...*/}`

Comment: `||` is a binary operation which can only deal with `Boolean` values. If any other value is provided then its converted to Boolean value and then operation is performed. `Number 0` or `String ''` is considered as `Boolean False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if `pos.x` exists, rather than by checking it's value.  You can do this with the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) function:

```
var x = pos.hasOwnProperty('x') ? pos.x : pos[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
var x = pos.x || pos[0] || 0,
    y = pos.y || pos[1] || 0;
```

The solution prevents falsy values and returns 0 as default value. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) about Logical Operators.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.